# Java / libGDX - Clean up object creation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

As you can see below, a lot of the code is very similar. So I was wondering, is there any way of compacting the creation of my buttons, such as by using a for loop?

```
private void initButtons() {
    Rectangle upButtonBounds = new Rectangle(55, 100, 75, 75);
    Rectangle downButtonBounds = new Rectangle(55, 0, 75, 75);
    Rectangle leftButtonBounds = new Rectangle(0, 50, 75, 75);
    Rectangle rightButtonBounds = new Rectangle(105, 50, 75, 75);
    Rectangle jumpButtonBounds = new Rectangle(VIEWPORT_WIDTH - 185, 115, 80, 80);
    Rectangle attackButtonBounds = new Rectangle(VIEWPORT_WIDTH - 185, 25, 80, 80);
    Rectangle magicButtonBounds = new Rectangle(VIEWPORT_WIDTH - 100, 75, 80, 80);

    upButton = new GameButton(upButtonBounds, "up");
    downButton = new GameButton(downButtonBounds, "down");
    leftButton = new GameButton(leftButtonBounds, "left");
    rightButton = new GameButton(rightButtonBounds, "right");
    jumpButton = new GameButton(jumpButtonBounds, "jump");
    attackButton = new GameButton(attackButtonBounds, "attack");
    magicButton = new GameButton(magicButtonBounds, "magic");

    addActor(upButton);
    addActor(downButton);
    addActor(leftButton);
    addActor(rightButton);
    addActor(jumpButton);
    addActor(attackButton);
    addActor(magicButton);
}
```

Comment: You can make a couple of array literals, one with the bounds and another with the names and then loop through the data instantiating the buttons and calling addActor.

Comment: @pvg how do I put the bounds for the rectangle into an array of floats and the loop through the floats?

Comment: @pvg never mind I figured it out, thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach

```
        float[][] bounds = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,5,7,8} };
        String[]  names  = { "foo", "bar"};

        for (int i = 0; i < bounds.length; i++)
        {
            float[] rect = bounds[i];
            addActor(new GameButton(new Rectangle(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]), names[i]));
        }
```